# How can I make the print() function not take the text in the input field with it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a console for my python applications, but i ran into a problem:
when printing something using the print() function, the text in the input field is also included. This is purely visual, because the program still works.

I tried searching online, but I do not even now what to search for and had no luck.

This is my code. It prints "foo" until the user types "exit":

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import time

def f(q):
    while True:
        print(q)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    p=mp.Process(target=f, args=("foo",))
    p.start()
    while True:
        comm=str(input())
        if comm=="exit":
            p.terminate()
            break
```

When the program is running, the user can still type, but when the program prints something, it also takes whatever is in the input field at the time:

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
efoo
xfoo
itfoo
```

When pressing "enter", the program still registers the input correctly and exits the program.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the problem. I am not trying to make the user unable to type while its printing, I am trying to prevent the print function from taking the text already in the input field.

Comment: Your `f()` method is simply printing `foo` over and over again (because that is what you passed in the `args`). Anything else you see is your typing and has nothing to do with the `f()` method in the `Process`.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want the program to print the unfinished input alongside "foo". As I said in the question, if, for example I type "exi" and don't press enter, the next time the program is printing, it will show "exi" before "foo" on the same line ("exifoo") and leave the input field empty.

Comment: Is it acceptable to prevent the `f()` method from printing anything until you finish typing input (until you hit `Enter`)?

Comment: If there isn't any other way of doing it, yes.

Comment: Is stopping the process the ONLY action you want the user to be able to take? (by typing exit)?

Comment: No, I thought it was a good example for a command. I want the user to be able to type commands whenever needed, but still be able to receive prints

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification of your code that only prints `foo` after you have finished your input typing (i.e., until you hit `Enter`):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Queue

def f(q, queue):
    while True:
        queue.get()
        print(q)

if __name__=="__main__":
    queue = Queue()
    p=mp.Process(target=f, args=("foo", queue))
    p.start()
    while True:
        comm=str(input())
        queue.put(None)
        if comm=="exit":
            p.terminate()
            break
```

Comment: Won't this block the entire process from executing until the user types something in? The call to `foo` will only be made each time the user enters something which seems highly undesirable

Comment: Well, I'l try to make it work using this method, but it isn't exactly what I wanted, I wanted it to still be able to show data, even if the user is not typing.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a GUI. One window for showing data, and another for user input.

Comment: I thought it would have been easier with only the command line but it seems that I will need a GUI afterall.

Answer (score 0):

If terminating the process is all you want your user to be able to do, then you can instruct them to enter Ctrl+C if they wish to stop the operation and then catch the KeyboardInterrupt exception that comes along with it.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import time

def f(q):
    while True:
        print(q)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    p=mp.Process(target=f, args=("foo",))
    print("Process starting. Use Ctrl+c anytime to stop it!")
    p.start()
    try:
        while True:
            input() # Trash command 
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Terminating process...")
        p.terminate()
        print("Process terminated...")
```

If you want to do more complicated commands then a GUI would be your best approach (as mentioned by John)